# Get the y value of a given x

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a simple question but have not found any answer..

Let's have a look at this code :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy

x=[0,1,2,3,4]
y=[5,3,40,20,1]
pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

It is plotted and all the points ared linked.

Let's say I want to get the y value of x=1,3.

How can I get the x values matching with y=30 ? (there are two)

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Using the basic math from school, y(1.3) = 14.1, x(30) = 1.73 and 2.5.

Comment: It's just an example, I need to dot that for a lot of points...

Comment: that's why I need a smarter way using a python maths lib

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`shapely`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) to find the intersections:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry as SG

x=[0,1,2,3,4]
y=[5,3,40,20,1]
line = SG.LineString(list(zip(x,y)))
y0 = 30
yline = SG.LineString([(min(x), y0), (max(x), y0)])
coords = np.array(line.intersection(yline))
print(coords[:, 0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axhline(y=y0, color='k', linestyle='--')
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')
ax.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], s=50, c='red')
plt.show()
```

finds solutions for `x` at:

```
[ 1.72972973  2.5       ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code might do what you want. The interpolation of y(x) is straight forward, as the x-values are monotonically increasing. The problem of finding the x-values for a given y is not so easy anymore, once the function is not monotonically increasing as in this case. So you still need to know roughly where to expect the values to be.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.optimize

x=np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
y=np.array([5,3,40,20,1])

#if the independent variable is monotonically increasing
print np.interp(1.3, x, y)

# if not, as in the case of finding x(y) here,
# we need to find the zeros of an interpolating function
y0 = 30.
initial_guess = 1.5 #for the first zero, 
#initial_guess = 3.0 # for the secon zero
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x,y,kind="linear")
fmin = lambda x: np.abs(f(x)-y0)
s = scipy.optimize.fmin(fmin, initial_guess, disp=False)
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

I use python 3.

```
print(numpy.interp(1.3, x, y))

Y = 30
eps = 1e-6
j = 0
for i, ((x0, x1), (y0, y1)) in enumerate(zip(zip(x[:-1], x[1:]), zip(y[:-1], y[1:]))):
    dy = y1 - y0
    if abs(dy) < eps:
        if y0 == Y:
            print('There are infinite number of solutions')
    else:
        t = (Y - y0)/dy
        if 0 < t < 1:
            sol = x0 + (x1 - x0)*t
            print('solution #{}: {}'.format(j, sol))
            j += 1
```

Comment: Many thanks
I tried your solution but it doesnt work if I want x for y=3 for example (as 3 is in the y list).
I am looking for an get_x_for_y() function that works for every y value.

Comment: ok, change `if 0 < t < 1:` to `if 0 <= t < 1:` and it will work also for these cases.